# Website copying question and answer from Stack Overflow and presenting it as theirs

Tags: support

Are websites allowed to copy questions with their answer(s) from Stack Overflow and present it as authored by them?

If no, what should one do?

Comment: They're not allowed to, no. See the content license. Nothing to really do about it though (unless you happen to have a lawyer on standby; stack doesn't care anymore). There's also a dupe for this

Comment: @Turamarth Yes and it references https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-should-i-do which does as well.

Comment: @zoe Sure, they don't care about scraper sites, but The Powers That Be *will* act if a site is masquerading as a Stack Exchange site, because such sites can do real damage.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, but based on the information presented, that isn't the case here

Comment: @Zoe Fair enough.